# ReferenceError: Vue is not defined (laravel)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-6

I know there have lots of similar questions of this but I couldn't find a solution from those.

Already installed npm of vue and successfully compiled using `npm run dev`, I don't know why it return this kind of error below.

> ReferenceError: Vue is not defined

This is my setup in my **app.js**:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

window.Vue = Vue;
Vue.use(VueRouter);

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

In my **welcome.blade.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Sample</button>
        </div>

        <script src="{{ mix('js/manifest.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ mix('js/vendor.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Someone knows where I went wrong?

Comment: try to add  below in bootstrap.js

`window.Vue = require('vue'); `

Comment: @Sehdev done already with that Sir but still error appears.

Comment: try `npm install`

Comment: @charles try running `npm run production`

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz still not working Sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious on what's inside your `bootstrap.js`. Maybe can you show us, might you import something that is using Vue, on which apparently fail to import.

Comment: exactly! I import my customed `Form.js` inside **bootstrap.js**. thanks